# Can anyone come up with a Custom Renderer solution to change the color of the underline in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms application that uses this code:

```
<Grid
    HeightRequest="50"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    x:Class="J.Templates.EntryGrid"
    x:Name="this"
    xmlns ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/form
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="lastColumnWidth" Width="150"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text1, Source={x:Reference this}}"  />
    <Entry Grid.Column="1"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               TextColor="{DynamicResource LabelLinkColor}"
               Keyboard="{Binding EntryKeyboardType,  Source={x:Reference this}}"
               Text="{Binding EntryText,  Source={x:Reference this}}"
               FontSize="{DynamicResource LabelTextFontSize}"
               FontFamily="{DynamicResource DefaultFont}"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    </Entry>
</Grid>
```

The iOS and Android views look like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can change the Android underline color and also (if possible) spacing of the gap between the underline and the numbers.

Comment: You want to remove the underline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to remove the underline, then you have to do it in a [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace CustomEntryUnderline.Android
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Background = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to change the underline color, you have to create a [Color state list resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource).

In the Android project, under `Resources` folder, create a new directory `Color`. In it, create a xml file, describing the `selector` drawable. Let's call it `editable_selector.xml`. Here's how it will look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#00ff00"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <item android:state_active="false" android:color="#0000ff"/>
</selector>
```

Here, you can change a lot of things, but in the xml selector, I have set the border to be blue by default, green when pressed and red when focused.

Then in your renderer, you'll have to set the native view's [BackgroundTintList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:backgroundTint). We'll be doing this again in the `OnElementChanged` method.

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control != null)
    {
        var colorStateList = Context.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.editable_selector);
        Control.BackgroundTintList = colorStateList;
    }
}
```

Here's a running gif:

[image]

You don't need to change the "gap", just adjust your layout, because currently the issue is not with the default offset, but with the way the layout is being rendered. Changing the offset should be considered a last resort.

However, if you still want to change the bottom padding between the text and the bottom border, again, in the `OnElementChanged` method, set the `Control`'s padding like this:

```cs
Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 120);
```

Here, I have set only a bottom padding of 120.

NB: It is not considered a good approach to create a renderer that will override all elements. Here, for simplicity, I am exporting the renderers for the built-in `Entry` type. It is better to wrap the `Entry` inside your own `CustomEntry` class in order to not modify the styles globally.

Comment: @Alan2 You should give the bounty if you accepted this answer by the way.